# Unifying lookahead and lookbehind into a single regex operator

Tags: .net, regex, syntactic-sugar, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I am making a simplified/sugary wrapper for regex which cuts out many of the more complicated regex functions (whilst still keeping the essentials for 99% of uses), and which also tries to tidy up the syntax a little.

In regards to negative lookahead/lookbehind, I found it confusing why they can't be combined into a single function. To clarify what I mean, let me demonstrate with an example:

I know you use negative lookbehind if you don't want to match the "mo" if it's preceded by "giz". So the expression `(?<!giz)mo` will handle that.

And I know you use negative lookahead if you don't want to match the "giz" part if it's followed by "mo". So the expression `giz(?!mo)` will handle that.

What I DON'T know is why regex can't figure this out for itself. In theory, I shouldn't need to specify whether it's ahead or behind - it should just look at the disallowed bit, and exclude any expression which contains that.

To further clarify, and maybe prove my point, I might get my sugary wrapper to interpret my own custom-purpose symbols - ⊄ and ⊅ - like this:

...Replace this: `giz⊄mo⊅` with this: `giz(?!mo)(?<!mo)`

...and replace this: `⊄giz⊅mo` with this: `(?!giz)(?<!giz)mo`

As you can see, in both instances, it's using both lookahead and lookbehind, so the user doesn't have to decide which one to use. You may say the user is being lazy, but then I can just say back Regex is being lazy for not doing this behind the scenes.

To restate the question in yet another way, what practical things can you do with `(?!xyz)` and/or `(?<!xyz)` that you can't do with the single: `(?!xyz)(?<!xyz)`? Why does Regex need two operators to apparently perform the functionality of essentially one?

I'm using .NET so lookbehind has full versatility.

Am I missing something?

Comment: They are both different.Regex engine works differently in both cases.Please read about it

Comment: vks: I have read about it, but any differences I see appear only superficial. I'm not interested in efficiency at this stage, only syntactic sugar. Perhaps give an example where it really matters to need to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, it's easy enough to say: "Well, just get the program to automatically decide the direction based on the position of any adjacent literals", so `(?<!xyz)house` or `.*(?<!xyz)house` and `house(?!xyz)` or `house(?!xyz).*` would all make sense. The rule would be "If the literal is to the left, use the lookahead operator, whilst if it's to the right, then use the lookbehind operator.". If both sides were literal, then the expression would be worthless anyway. This holds *most* of the time (though as pointed out by hvd, it won't work if the number of chars in `xyz` overlaps a char in the adjacent text which ISN'T a literal - e.g: the asterisk in `(?!xyz)xy*z`).

But further problems come when both sides are not a literal.

For example, try the regex: `the ..(?!u).. house` against the text "the blue house". Obviously, `?!` would act differently to `?<!` here, and either option may be desired.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of where you might want `(?!xyz)`, but not `(?!xyz)(?<!xyz)`, is in the regex `xyz(?!xyz)`, to match `xyz` that is not immediately followed by another `xyz`. Just try it with `xyz(?!xyz)(?<!xyz)` and you will see that it never matches: the point where `(?<!xyz)` is checked is always preceded by `xyz`, because you just matched that.

Comment: That's an interesting observation, but it seems like a corner case. I can't imagine that this is all it would be useful for. Can you think of anything else as well?

Comment: @DanW It's not as much as a corner case as you might think. It isn't just when the "not" pattern matches exactly, you have the same problem with `xyz(?!z)(?<!z)`. And this is actually fairly common one, at least for me, when searching for a word that ends in "ss", but someone used to spell it with just one "s", and I want to find all occurrences of the word that don't have "ss". As for other things, if you're looking for cases where `(?!xyz)` at the end of a regex does something differently from `(?!xyz)(?<!xyz)`, then it will necessarily involve `(?<!xyz)` finding a match when it shouldn't.

Comment: Oh I see, that's unfortunate. Is there any workaround so that I can just add the single op to my app instead of both ops? Perhaps it might be possible for me to automate it so that the `(?!xyz)` is inserted by the program if it's at the end of the expression, and `(?<!xyz)` is used if the program sees it's at the beginning. And if it's in the middle, perhaps either could be used. Would there be any harm in doing that?

Comment: @DanW Well, sometimes you *do* want a forward negative match at the start of a regex, or a backwards negative match at the end. You might think `(?!xyz)xy*z` is a more readable form of `xz|xyy+z`, for instance. You can make guesses about what the author's intent, or you can make the author spell it out. Yes, the latter requires some work on the part of the author.

Comment: Fair enough. Also, I cooked up an expression where you're forced to give the direction. Try the regex: `the ..(?!u).. house` against the text "the blue house". It doesn't make much sense against literals, but with things like wildcard chars, suddenly it starts to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point, I am afraid.

Look-behind is checking characters before the place it is in the pattern, look-ahead is checking characters after.

`abc(?!xyz)` checks if `abc` is not followed by `xyz`, and it makes sense: see no match with `abcxyzz` [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=abc(%3F!xyz)&i=My%20abc%20abcxyzz%20and%20xyzz)).

`(?<!xyz)abc` will check for characters before `abc`, and there is a match in `abcxyzz` (see [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!xyz)abc&i=My%20abc%20abcxyzz%20and%20xyzz)).

Now, in `abc(?!xyz)(?<!xyz)`, the `(?<!xyz)` makes no sense since it is always true (we have `abc`, not `xyz`). `abc(?!xyz)(?<!xyz)` = `abc(?!xyz)`.

In `(?!xyz)(?<!xyz)abc`, the `(?!xyz)` part is always true since `abc` is not `xyz`. `(?!xyz)(?<!xyz)abc` = `(?<!xyz)abc`.

**There is no point in using the look-aheads with look-behinds the way you suggest, it only adds to the overhead and decreases performance bringing no unification, but pain for the engine.**

Comment: The OP knows this already, and is looking to use `(?!xyz)(?<!xyz)` in all cases, simply to avoid having to think about which of the two to use. The OP already realises that one or the other will have no effect. An explanation on the decreased performance could be useful to give the OP a compelling argument not to go on with this idea.

Comment: And this is no good since the most important is *where* you place the look-around and what is its contents.

Comment: hvd is right. I realize the other would have no effect. The reason I want this is because I would prefer a single operator rather than two in my interface to make things simpler. Apart from performance considerations, I'd be interested to see what extra functionality two operators bring to the table.

Comment: @hvd: Is the performance only going to half at worst with my combined op? If so, that's not a great concern. I'd rather have a simpler set of operators.

Comment: @DanW How much it affects performance depends heavily on the exact regex used. It could be much worse than that, but it will usually be much less worse than that.